# PowerPivot Count Occurrences of Partial String in Table1 Column Based upon Table 2 Column

Tags: excel, calculated-columns, powerpivot

I am learning PowerPivot by reading posts but I haven't found an answer for this issue.

I have Table 1 (Products) with 2 columns (number and description) and about 100 rows.

***Products***

```
| Item | Description |
| 001  | Blue Widget |  
| 002  | Green Widget|  
| 003  | Red Widget|
```

I have a second table, Invoice. It has multiple columns, but for my purposes the important column is ItemsPurchased. That column will have a string of product items. For example

```
|InvoiceNum|ItemsPurchased|
|  3843  | 001, 003         |
|  3953  | 002              |
|  4002. | 003, 002         |
```

There are about 6000 rows which will keep growing. They are not not related since the ItemsPurchased could have multiple Item Numbers.

I am trying to get a calculated field in the Products Table to look like this:

```
| Item |  Description  | Count
| 001  |  Blue Widget  |   1     |  
| 002  |  Green Widget |   2     |   
| 003  |  Red Widget   |   2     |
```

I made a measure calculating this:

001:=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Invoice),SEARCH("001",Invoice[ItemsPurchased],,0))

But the problem with this is I would need to write 100 measures and I would not be able to filter them to a Top 10 list in the pivot table.

I found on another website the following formula:

=CALCULATE(COUNTA(Invoice[ItemsPurchased]),FILTER(Invoice,Invoice[ItemsPurchased]]=Products[Item]))

but it doesn't search for a partial phrase and it doesn't list the `Products[Item]` column in the auto populate of the formula bar. I have tried different ways of combining the formula in the measure with the formula above, but I get various errors.

Is this even something that can be done in PowerPivot? I don't understand how to make a calculated column that will take the item number from each row in that column and count the number of occurrences in the Invoice Table's ItemsPurchased column.

Any tips on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If at all possible, you should reshape your second table so that each distinct item is on a separate row. The DAX is waaay easier with a better data model.

Comment: I agree with @AlexisOlson  I originally thought you could leverage the SEARCH function, but that will return false positives.  0011 would also catch 001.  Prior to loading to the Data Model bring your table into Power Query and split ItemsPurchased to rows on the ", " delimiter.  You can then fill down the other columns to provide a full data set.